# Nix on Vscode terminal

Tags: macos, nix, apple-m1

I'am having issue using nix on my Vscode terminal, if I type `nix-shell` on my terminal everything work just fine but if I try on Vscode terminal it says:
`zsh: command not found: nix-shell`
I already had this issue before and fix it with adding my `PATH` in the settings.json file at terminal.integrated.env.osx.
The paths that I add are `"terminal.integrated.env.osx": { "PATH" : "/Users/my_name/.nix-profile/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/my_name/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/my_name/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin", "NIX_PATH" : "/Users/my_name/.nix-defexpr/channels"},`
I also don't know why my PATH is so long and if I did something wrong.

Nevertheless adding those line on my settings.json fie fixed the issue for a while but it doesn't work anymore and I don't know why.
I am on a MacBook Air (M1, 2020), macos bigsur 11.2.3
I am using the default Terminal.app application provided by mac.
I tried to put integrated and external on terminal settings in Vscode, neither of them work

Thanks for reading and sorry if my explanation aren't good.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this? Did you try a web search?

Comment: I have done many research without any solution yet, I found simular issue and I found the first solution as I said  (adding my PATH to the settings.json file)
I have set the nix env on vscode and it work perfectly, vscode know where to find the file provided by nix and there is no error while editing the code
The only issue is the terminal that doesn't find the command